# Better way to Split files into 80% and 20% for building model and prediction in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, classification

I am trying to divide my HDFS file into 2 parts/files
**80%** and **20%** for classification algorithm(80% for modelling and 20% for prediction)
Please provide suggestion for the same.

To take 80% and 20% to 2 seperate files we need to know the exact number of record in the data set.And it is only known if we go through the data set once.
so we need to write **1** MapReduce Job for just counting the number of records and
**2** nd Mapreduce Job for separating 80% and 20% into 2 files using Multiple Inputs.

Am I in the right track or there is any alternative for the same.

But again a small confusion **how to check if the reducer get filled with 80% data**.

Comment: why not split file by split command and post to hdfs instead of running map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Random` for splitting the dataset and `MultipleOutputs` to write data into separate paths. It can be done with only one map-only job. Here is an example of mapper that you could use:

```
public class Splitter extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, NullWritable> {
    MultipleOutputs mos;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (rnd.nextDouble() < 0.8) {
            mos.write(key, value, "learning-set");
        } else {
            mos.write(key, value, "test-set");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        mos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey: A small confusion Once it is a maponly job,each mapper can produce 80% and 20% data right.say if I have 2 mapper,each map produce 80% and 20% od data. so how can we make sure that each map writes accurate 80% to learning set and 20% to test set?So it will be better to write the code in Reducer right?

Comment: With random we can't be sure that map will write exactly 80% of data to learning set, it can be 80.5% or 79.5%. Is that a problem? Regardless to the number of mappers you will have folder named `learning-set` with ~80% of data at the end of the job.